# Conditional assignment in polars dataframe

Tags: python, python-polars

I am wondering if there's a way to handle conditional assignment in polars dataframe without using numpy related.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'team': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
                'conference': ['East', 'East', 'East', 'West', 'West', 'East'],
                'points': [11, 8, 10, 6, 6, 5],
                'rebounds': [7, 7, 6, 9, 12, 8]})
df = pl.from_pandas(df); df

┌──────┬────────────┬────────┬──────────┐
│ team ┆ conference ┆ points ┆ rebounds │
│ ---  ┆ ---        ┆ ---    ┆ ---      │
│ str  ┆ str        ┆ i64    ┆ i64      │
╞══════╪════════════╪════════╪══════════╡
│ A    ┆ East       ┆ 11     ┆ 7        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ A    ┆ East       ┆ 8      ┆ 7        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ A    ┆ East       ┆ 10     ┆ 6        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B    ┆ West       ┆ 6      ┆ 9        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B    ┆ West       ┆ 6      ┆ 12       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ C    ┆ East       ┆ 5      ┆ 8        │
└──────┴────────────┴────────┴──────────┘
```

Using numpy, we could do:

```
conditions = [
    df['points'].le(6) & df['rebounds'].le(9),
    df['points'].gt(10) & df['rebounds'].gt(6)
]
choicelist = ['Bad','Good']
df['rating']=np.select(conditions, choicelist, 'Aveg')
```

```
Expected output:
┌──────┬────────────┬────────┬──────────┬────────┐
│ team ┆ conference ┆ points ┆ rebounds ┆ rating │
│ ---  ┆ ---        ┆ ---    ┆ ---      ┆ ---    │
│ str  ┆ str        ┆ i64    ┆ i64      ┆ str    │
╞══════╪════════════╪════════╪══════════╪════════╡
│ A    ┆ East       ┆ 11     ┆ 7        ┆ Good   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ A    ┆ East       ┆ 8      ┆ 7        ┆ Aveg   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ A    ┆ East       ┆ 10     ┆ 6        ┆ Aveg   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B    ┆ West       ┆ 6      ┆ 9        ┆ Bad    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B    ┆ West       ┆ 6      ┆ 12       ┆ Aveg   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ C    ┆ East       ┆ 5      ┆ 8        ┆ Bad    │
└──────┴────────────┴────────┴──────────┴────────┘
```

Comment: You don't need pandas to create a `DataFrame` from a dictionary. It is clutter in the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can chain `when -> then -> otherwise` expressions.

```py
pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "team": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C"],
        "conference": ["East", "East", "East", "West", "West", "East"],
        "points": [11, 8, 10, 6, 6, 5],
        "rebounds": [7, 7, 6, 9, 12, 8]
     }
)

df.with_column(
    pl.when((pl.col("points") <= 6) & (pl.col("rebounds") <= 9))
    .then("Bad")
    .when((pl.col("points") > 10) & (pl.col("rebounds") > 6))
    .then("Good")
    .otherwise("Aveg")
    .alias("rating")
)
```

```
shape: (6, 5)
┌──────┬────────────┬────────┬──────────┬────────┐
│ team ┆ conference ┆ points ┆ rebounds ┆ rating │
│ ---  ┆ ---        ┆ ---    ┆ ---      ┆ ---    │
│ str  ┆ str        ┆ i64    ┆ i64      ┆ str    │
╞══════╪════════════╪════════╪══════════╪════════╡
│ A    ┆ East       ┆ 11     ┆ 7        ┆ Good   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ A    ┆ East       ┆ 8      ┆ 7        ┆ Aveg   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ A    ┆ East       ┆ 10     ┆ 6        ┆ Aveg   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B    ┆ West       ┆ 6      ┆ 9        ┆ Bad    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ B    ┆ West       ┆ 6      ┆ 12       ┆ Aveg   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ C    ┆ East       ┆ 5      ┆ 8        ┆ Bad    │
└──────┴────────────┴────────┴──────────┴────────┘
```

Comment: Completely forgot we could do extending `when/then` - thanks!