# Conditional replacement polars dataframe in python

Tags: python, python-polars

I am experimenting with a polars dataframe. The first column stores strings or null-values, the second numbers or null values. The rest are some columns with non-null data.

I try to replace the null values with a fixed value:

```
dataframe = dataframe.with_column(pl.when(pl.col("Column1").is_null()).then("String"))
dataframe = dataframe.with_column(pl.when(pl.col("Column2").is_null()).then(0))
```

I get the error `TypeError: with_column expects a single Expr or Series. Consider using` with_columns `if you need multiple columns.`, but choosing `with_columns()` raises `ValueError: Expected an expression, got <polars.internals.whenthen.WhenThen object at`.

My original idea comes from the related post [Conditional assignment in polars dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74122921/conditional-assignment-in-polars-dataframe), but I do not see my mistake. What am I missing?

Comment: could you make your example reproducible please? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.fill_null()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.fill_null.html#polars.Expr.fill_null) can be used to replace the nulls directly.

```py
df.with_columns(
   pl.col("Column1").fill_null("String"),
   pl.col("Column2").fill_null(0)
)
```

```py
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ Column1 ┆ Column2 ┆ Column3 │
│ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ str     ┆ i64     ┆ str     │
╞═════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ foo     ┆ 0       ┆ a       │
│ String  ┆ 0       ┆ b       │
│ bar     ┆ 1       ┆ c       │
└─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just missing `otherwise`?

Adapting the example from the linked question:

```py
In [8]: import pandas as pd
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame({'team': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
   ...:                 'conference': ['East', 'East', 'East', 'West', 'West', 'East'],
   ...:                 'points': [11, 8, 10, 6, 6, 5],
   ...:                 'rebounds': [7, 7, 6, 9, 12, 8]})
   ...: df = pl.from_pandas(df); df
Out[8]:
shape: (6, 4)
┌──────┬────────────┬────────┬──────────┐
│ team ┆ conference ┆ points ┆ rebounds │
│ ---  ┆ ---        ┆ ---    ┆ ---      │
│ str  ┆ str        ┆ i64    ┆ i64      │
╞══════╪════════════╪════════╪══════════╡
│ A    ┆ East       ┆ 11     ┆ 7        │
│ A    ┆ East       ┆ 8      ┆ 7        │
│ A    ┆ East       ┆ 10     ┆ 6        │
│ B    ┆ West       ┆ 6      ┆ 9        │
│ B    ┆ West       ┆ 6      ┆ 12       │
│ C    ┆ East       ┆ 5      ┆ 8        │
└──────┴────────────┴────────┴──────────┘

In [9]: df.with_column(pl.when(pl.col("team").is_null()).then("String").otherwise(pl.col('team')).alias('new_column'))
Out[9]:
shape: (6, 5)
┌──────┬────────────┬────────┬──────────┬────────────┐
│ team ┆ conference ┆ points ┆ rebounds ┆ new_column │
│ ---  ┆ ---        ┆ ---    ┆ ---      ┆ ---        │
│ str  ┆ str        ┆ i64    ┆ i64      ┆ str        │
╞══════╪════════════╪════════╪══════════╪════════════╡
│ A    ┆ East       ┆ 11     ┆ 7        ┆ A          │
│ A    ┆ East       ┆ 8      ┆ 7        ┆ A          │
│ A    ┆ East       ┆ 10     ┆ 6        ┆ A          │
│ B    ┆ West       ┆ 6      ┆ 9        ┆ B          │
│ B    ┆ West       ┆ 6      ┆ 12       ┆ B          │
│ C    ┆ East       ┆ 5      ┆ 8        ┆ C          │
└──────┴────────────┴────────┴──────────┴────────────┘
```